# Projective transformation fitting

Tags: algorithm, math

Given set of points in 3D ( X = (x1, x2, x3), Y = (y1, y2, y3) ), how can I fit  transformation from X to Y?

As far as I know this is called projective transformation.
Here is example of X and Y.

Blue and red lines in X are parallel, but they are not parallel in Y.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was used to create these graphs? Just curious.

Comment: see for example http://tinyurl.com/5wkhaf8

Comment: I'm offering a bounty of 500 to solve this very similar question: 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414809/extract-projective-homography-from-two-kinect-depth-maps

Answer (score 2):

Projective transformations in 3d have an associated 4x4 matrix (modulo a constant multiplication). You can find the matrix with least square fitting.

Comment: True, and we know, but not terribly helpful

Answer (score 1):

Well. I found some useful information:

This transformation is non-linear and it is not possible to represent non-linear transformation with a matrix. There are some tricks such as using homogenous coordinates. but it doesn't make all non-linear transformations representable using matrices.
However, approximating a nonlinear function by a linear function is possible.

Comment: The transformation is projective. Projective transformations are represented with matrices defined up to a multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 1):

So, the task is to **find best fitting [linear transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix)**, right?

**There is a simple solution using linear regression.**

Say the transformation matrix is named `A` and has dimensions 3x3. And say you have `N` vectors (points) in 3D before and after the transformation - so you have matrices X and Y of 3 rows and N columns. Then the transformation is:

```
Y = A X + B
```

where B is a vector of length 3 and specifies the shift. You can rewrite the matrix multiplication using indices:

```
y[i,j] = sum(k=1..3)(a[i,k] * x[k,j])  + b[i]
```

for i = 1..3 and j = 1 .. N. So, you have 12 unknown variables (a, b), and 3 * N equations. For N >= 4, you simply find the best solution using **linear regression**.

For example, in R it is very easy:

```
# input data
X = matrix(c(c(0, 0, 0), c(1, 0, 0), c(0, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1)), nrow = 3)
Y = matrix(c(c(1, 0, 1), c(2, 0, 1), c(1, 1, 1), c(1, 1, 2)), nrow = 3)
# expected transformation: A is identity matrix, b is [1, 0, 1]
N = dim(Y)[2]

# transform data for regression
a1 = rbind(t(X), matrix(rep(0, 3*2*N), ncol = 3))
a2 = rbind(matrix(rep(0, 3*N), ncol = 3), t(X), matrix(rep(0, 3*N), ncol = 3))
a3 = rbind(matrix(rep(0, 3*2*N), ncol = 3), t(X))
b1 = rep(1:0, c(N, 2*N))
b2 = rep(c(0, 1, 0), each = N)
b3 = rep(0:1, c(2*N, N))
y = as.vector(t(Y))

# do the regression
summary(lm(y ~ 0 + a1 + a2 + a3 + b1 + b2 + b3))
```

And the output is:

```
[...]

Coefficients:
      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
a11  1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
a12 -2.220e-16         NA      NA       NA
a13 -3.612e-32         NA      NA       NA
a21  7.850e-17         NA      NA       NA
a22  1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
a23 -1.743e-32         NA      NA       NA
a31  0.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
a32  0.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
a33  1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
b1   1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA
b2  -7.850e-17         NA      NA       NA
b3   1.000e+00         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     1,      Adjusted R-squared:   NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 12 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

as expected.

Comment: Not linear transformation. Projective transformation. But this should be easy to adapt (projective transformations are roughly speaking 4x4 matrices whose entries sum to one).

Comment: The OP's request is indeed projective, but a linear projection would satisfy me. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with R. Could you possibly provide code (using EMGU+OpenCV if necessary) that I could translate to C# or VB.Net? Thanks.

Comment: @smirkingman, just use any library for linear regression to estimate matrices A and B as parameters, as I sketched above (probably use the second equation with indices). Or, if you don't find any library for C#, you can either [interface R from C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-r-interface), or look at how linear regression works and write your own expressions for parameter estimates.