# is there a way to call R functions from C# and retrieve the result in C#

Tags: c#, r

Is there a way to call R functions from C# and retrieve the result in C#?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-sharp-r-interface

Comment: I asked another question elsewhere on stackoverflow that would be able to be applied as an answer here as the concept would be the same.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40292945/is-it-possible-to-run-r-code-from-unity-c-sharp-in-mono-or-net-on-osx

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Given there is a COM interface to R, you can use C#'s COM interop to control it.

See this article for more details: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RtoCSharp.aspx

Answer (score 16):

R.NET (rdotnet) is designed to do this:

- Docs: https://rdotnet.github.io/rdotnet/
- Source: https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet
- NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/R.NET

Older versions can be found here:

- https://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/
- http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

Comment: https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet . It is also supposed to be on Nuget, though I have not verified this.

Comment: Looks like the Github pages are gone. I assume that this is the current one: https://github.com/rdotnet/rdotnet