# Free library for regression in c#

Tags: c#, linear-regression

Do you know of a free library in .net that I can use to fit a multivariate regression. I want to get the coefficients, and all the statistics (p-values, Std Errors, Goodness of Fitness, etc). I've tried Meta.Numerics, which works great, but it does not have some of the statistics.

Comment: This may provide what you need: http://www.alglib.net/

Comment: alglib.net is great, but it does not calculate the statistics I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could R. be a solution?

There are several ways you can incorporate R in C#

1. http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/

   R.NET enables .NET Framework to collaborate with R statistical computing. R.NET requires .NET Framework 4 and R.dll. You already have the DLL if you installed R environment, and you need no other extra installations. Enjoy your programming with R language.

or 2 using the interop solution, that is also used here :

[C# - R interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-r-interface)

Comment: I don't know, the accepted solution in my second link state :  'I installed 2.11.1 and it worked out of box.' but that's R. For .net, why use 2?

Comment: Because I want to embed this in SQLCLR (the CLR inside SQL Server 2008).. and that only accepts .net 2.0

Comment: @Nestor, Sorry, I cannot answer that one by heart, but I suppose the interop. solution will work also in 2.0