# Regression in c#

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free library for regression in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594308/free-library-for-regression-in-c-sharp)

Do you know of a free library in .net that I can use to fit a multivariate regression. I want to get the coefficients, and all the statistics (p-values, Std Errors, Goodness of Fitness, etc). I've tried Meta.Numerics, which works great, but it does not have some of the statistics.

Comment: I have migrated since it is not a question about theoretical or practical aspects of regression but a pure programming question about  selecting a good library to do very certain job.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594308/free-library-for-regression-in-c