# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013: when Integrating R with C#:

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, r

I am trying to interface R with C# web application.I tried many solutions being provided but couldn't get it through. Error I am getting is: Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013

## Steps I followed were:

1. Installing R 2.15.1 for windows xp (32 bit)
2. Installed R_Scilab_DCOM3.0-1B5
3. Loaded rscproxy_1.3-1 package in the R/R.15.1/library
4. Set the System Variable path to C:/Program Files/R/R.15.1/bin
5. Added 3 COM references-STATCONNECTORCLNTLib,StatConnectorCommonLib,STATCONNECTORSRVLib
   Code:

private StatConnectorClass _statconnector = new STATCONNECTORSRVLib.StatConnectorClass();
_statconnector.Init("R");--> Line shows the **Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040013**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-sharp-r-interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the COM method to interface to c# some years ago, but I gave up because on each version change there were problems similar to that you mentioned. In addition, the licensing scheme of R(D)COM is a bit obscure to me, and the .NET/COM/R tour has too many corners.

My current choice is [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/), which is well maintained and has never let me down. I had written [my own test bed](http://www.menne-biomed.de/uni/rserve.zip) for c#, but I consider it obsolete because [RserveCLI](http://rservecli.codeplex.com/) is more complete.

[R.NET](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/) in theory is a better concept, but for strange reasons it is considered "stable" by the author, which is highly euphemistic because of the many bugs mainly in memory management. Too bad it never took off.

Comment: Thank you @Dieter for your immediate response. I tried using R.NET and got perfect results . Further I also Downloaded RAndFriends package from the http://rcom.univie.ac.at/download.html. which helped to resolve my problem. Thanks again Dieter for your response.

Comment: Howard Mansell has contacted me, telling me about his F# related work with R.NET: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider. I wish there would be a little storm on the R.NET site asking for a new release with the more stable memory management.

Answer (score 4):

I believe R.NET is a much better way to access R functionality from C#.  It all runs in-process and so doesn't require an external R process to be running.

If you install [the NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/R.NET), you will get version 1.5.  This incorporates some memory management fixes I made that address most of the crashes people have reported.  As Dieter points out, we use R.NET extensively via the [F# RProvider](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider), and it is extremely stable with the latest version.  The RProvider also comes with a wrapper generator that generates wrapper functions for R functions which can be used from C#.  So for example you could call the plot function from C# as R.plot(...params...).  And you get Intellisense.

Comment: I have tried the NuGet version 1.5 today with my graphics example code that crashed the system in version 1.4, and it seems to work Ok now. Not yet tested in detail, but will revive my demo.