# R.NET With C# Web Application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, r

I am trying to integrate R with C# **Web Application** using R.NET
I loaded the R.NET dll and called the RDOTNET library in the .cs file which I named as R.cs class. 
The Code is ::

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using RDotNet;

namespace Rtrial_1
{
    public class R
    {
        public R() 
        {

            REngine.SetDllDirectory(@"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\i386");
            using (REngine engine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" })) //quiet mode
            {
                NumericVector group1 = engine.CreateNumericVector(new double[] { 30.02, 29.99, 30.11, 29.97, 30.01, 29.99 });
                engine.SetSymbol("group1", group1);
                NumericVector group2 = engine.EagerEvaluate("group2 <- c(29.89, 29.93, 29.72, 29.98, 30.02, 29.98)").AsNumeric();
                Console.WriteLine("Group1: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", group1));
            }

        } 
    }
}
```

The Application has failed to start because Rlapack.dll was not found.Re-installing the application may fix this problem. I tired reinstalling the R but it didn't worked out.
As well as the bin folder contains the respective dll.

Please someone help me. I am working on VS 2010, R-1.15.1

Comment: Try to add C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\i386 to your search path.

Comment: @Dieter:Thank you sir.I resolved this by adding and reinstalling the R. But I have another query to be resolved :). I am trying to integrate R with C# by using R-(D)COM. I am getting an error at Init. I have listed my query here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834704/intregating-r-with-vs2010exception-from-hresult-0x80040013 If possible please try to help me out resolving this issue.

Comment: Hi @Dieter. I encountering another problem regd the same, May you please help me to see the issue I am facing. Thanks in advance sir.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201574/rengine-rengine-rengine-createinstancerdotnet-new-q-stops-the-exe

Comment: You may note that in the discussion mentioned by @iMortalitySX at the end the author comes to the same conclusion: use RServeCli instead. This is the type of memory management problem that always comes up with R.NET, but only after you got many things working. See also my "give up" on http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/workitem/7 .

Comment: @DieterMenne: I think you overgeneralize the memory management issues and relay advice based on where R.NET was several months or years ago. While not discarding your prior difficulties using R.NET, you may want to reassess where it is up to.  (Edit: Oops, sorry missed the 2012 date of these comments. Put it on lack of sleep. Nevertheless, please reconsider)

Comment: Re Memory Management: Please re-check the page after waking up. There is a comment from me at a prominent location on the subject. R.NET currently ís reasonably stable. There are some problems due racing condition occasionally when using the Graph-Hook I posted (moving the mouse too early crashes), but that seems acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Install this and Change Your Reference Path of Your C Drive

https://www.google.co.in/search?q=install+R+version+2.13.0+in+windows&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&gws_rd=cr&ei=kBCCUozfLI6VrAe8qYHoCg

Answer (score 0):

Comments on versions or R and R.NET you (seem to) use:

- `SetDllDirectory` is an obsolete method in the API. You do not
  explicitly state which version of R.NET you are using.  I would
  encourage you to move to the latest R.NET (1.5.5) if needed, and preferably the latest
  R in the 3.0 series if you can, though R 2.15.1 should be working
  fine.
- Talking about the latest, I've also done some work to alleviate
  the cruft needed to set up environment variables, which should make
  it to the next release. If you are up for it you can check out and compile the latest from source, on a branch I can indicate. Coupled to that branch is some sample code in development at https://github.com/jmp75/rdotnet-onboarding/tree/rdotnet-dev/WebApplicationRdn.

Regarding your particular use case, a couple of pointers:

- There are some differences in behavior with older R.NET releases and R 2.15.x series in http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/353957, in particular with comments on rlapack.dll
- The most recent discussion on R.NET with ASP.NET (which is what I suppose is what you use) is at http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/462947. There are quite a few others posts in this vein that will provide advice on your issue. The latest status, as I judge is that yes, running from ASP.NET is still problematic. And it may be due to undocumented behaviors in the native R engine. Keep watching that discussion nevertheless.

Cheers