# REngine rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" } stops the execution further when called second time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, r

I am plotting the forecast graph by using R.NET  and using ASP.NET MVC3. At first time, it creates an instance of RENgine. by

```
REngine rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" })
```

and plots the graph as required. But when I call this same method second time by choosing another graph to be plotted, it stops to move further after this,. Please someone help me to figure out where I am going wrong. The code I have used is

```
using (REngine rengine = REngine.CreateInstance("RDotNet", new[] { "-q" }))
    {
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("YrTimeSeries<-c(123,234,255,456)");
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("tsValue<-ts(YrTimeSeries,frequency=1," 
                               + dt_StartYr.Rows[0][0].ToString() + ")");
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("library(Cairo);");
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("library(forecast)");
        rengine.EagerEvaluate(@"CairoPNG('C:\\Documents and Settings\\a\\im.png);
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("plot(forecast(tsValue,h=5),main='Immunization')");
        rengine.EagerEvaluate("graphics.off();");
        rengine.Close();
        rengine.Dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: You do not have to call .Close() or .Dispose() inside of the using block...  it's kind of one of the points of the using block is that it will automatically call the Dispose method (which in this case also calls Close()).

Comment: Are you trying to use two instances of REngine at the same time?

Comment: Ok sir.I thought i need to explicitly close the rengine. But Sir removing them also is not solving my problem.

Comment: No. I am not using two instances

Comment: No that was just a C#ism.  Anyways, [Check out this MSDN on R.NET in parallel](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/267550).  I know you are not creating two at once, but it looks like this leads to exactly your same issue.

Comment: What i am trying to do is : At first time, users sees the forecasting graph. at the same page, the user can choose another options to view the other respective graphs. I am encountering a problem when the complier reaches at  REngine rengine = REngine.CreateInstance(“RDotNet”, new[] { “-q” }

Comment: Thanks @iMortalitySX for providing me the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just reposting a comment that I had made about where to find the issue, but as everyone knows you don't get points for upvotes on comments.

Check out [this MSDN on R.NET in parallel](http://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/267550). I know you are not creating two at once, but it looks like this leads to exactly your same issue.