# Launching an R graph from within C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, r, visual-studio-2012

I'm writing a console app in C#, and I'd like to use the R engine to pop up a graph in a window.

Does anyone know if this is possible from Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Not sure if this is really related but there's an F# typeprovider that interops with R. Haven't tried it myself though: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharpRProvider

Comment: In addition, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pull a graph from R into .NET, and display it on a WinForms panel:

[image]

First, we have to install Statconn, which is the bridge between .NET and R. Its important to install the correct version (it won't work if there is the wrong mix of x32 and x64). The easiest way to ensure this is to install Statconn from within the R console:

```
# Install Statconn bridge.
# Load the "rcom" package:
install.packages('rcom')
# Load the library 'rcom':
library('rcom')
```

At this point, it will give an error that you don't have the `Statconn` library installed. This is easy to fix:

```
install.packages('statconn')
```

This will automatically install the correct version of the StatConn bridge, which is a standalone windows installer.

Now that we have installed Statconn, we can open up the sample .NET project in `C:\Program Files (x86)\statconn\DCOM\samples\Graphics.NET`. This sample .NET project shows how to use R to plot graphics from within a C# WinForms project.

p.s. There is also other sample code for Python, C++, VBS, jscript, etc.

### Update

If you cannot get this working, try `R.Net`, which is probably a better choice because Statconn hasn't been updated in a while, and is quite picky with less than perfect mixtures of '32-bit' / '64-bit' / 'supported R versions'.

Comment: This doesnt work for R version 3.2.3. Is there a work around for the current version??

Comment: @Vini The most likely issue is a 32-bit vs. 64-bit. Everything has to be either one or the other, including the version of R and Statconn. I also vaguely recal that newer versions of R did not work - perhaps try an older verison to see if this works?

Comment: :Thanks for your input. I am using R.Net. so things are fixed.

Comment: @Vini Good move, I think R.Net is probably a better choice compared to Statconn (which hasn't been updated in a while).

Comment: Ihave used r.net. I am able to get graph on console. Is there a way to get it doen for web app. It doesnt seem to work in my web app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260419/getting-r-plot-to-c-sharp-web-application. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260419/getting-r-plot-to-c-sharp-web-application]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. What you need is to execute R code from C#. By searching on google I found the following project: [The R Statistical Language and C#.NET: Foundations](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25819/The-R-Statistical-Language-and-C-NET-Foundations) by **Jeff B. Cromwell**.

Here is some code to generate a histogram plot of twenty normal random variables:

```
//using STATCONNECTORCLNTLib; 
StatConnector test1 = new StatConnectorClass(); 
test1.Init("R"); 
test1.Evaluate("x <- rnorm(20)"); 
test1.EvaluateNoReturn("hist(x)");
```

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get this to work, as I think things have shifted in both R and Statconn since this release. My answer shows a method of ensuring that the correct version of Statconn is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

As said by others , `R.net` is promising project (still unstable).

The philosophy behind is to manipulate R objects within .net framework.

I think if all what you want is to pop a graph in a window, it is better to create a.bat file where you call your R script using the very good `Rscript` command.

Something like this should work for you:

In your c# side , you call

```
Process.Start("launcher.bat");
```

and you define your `launcher.bat`:

```
PATH PATH_TO_R/R-version/bin;%path%
cd PATH_TO_R_SCRIPT
Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Even if does not look elegant, it is often the easiest method. @Fuex solution via RDCOM works if you stay in one environment, but leads to frequent problems when R versions change. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834704/exception-from-hresult-0x80040013-when-intregating-r-with-c/12871905#12871905

Comment: @DieterMenne Thanks for your comment! for a console app(asked by the OP)I think it is a coherent solution! I tried your bed test for rserve , but it is doesn't for express c#2010, maybe you use a newer version?

Comment: Forget my version, it was a VERY early shot, and I have not maintained it after  Oliver Haynold's http://rservecli.codeplex.com/ came up. Caveat: It's almost 2 year ago I had used it, so I do not know about the current state.

Comment: @DieterMenne Can you please put some of theses remarks in a comment and I will hapy to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The package R.net might be a good place to start looking at the results of a quick google. Alternatively, you could use a more basic approach by creating R scripts that can be called from the commandline, and use system calls from C#.

Comment: Apparently, R.NET doesn't allow you to display any graphics. Pity. However, in theory, it might be possible to capture the bitmap from R, then manually display the bitmap using WinForms (I have done this in Mathematica, and it works beautifully).

Comment: The 3-D plot package RGL has an option rgl.snapshot which creates a png file. Ideally, I would find some call that returned the bitmap rather than displaying it on screen (writing to a png file would be doable, but slow).