# Visual Odometry using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to implement monocular (single camera) Visual Odometry in OpenCV Python. Wikipedia gives the commonly used steps for approach here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_odometry
I calculated Optical Flow using Lucas Kanade tracker. The code is given here http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_video/py_lucas_kanade/py_lucas_kanade.html
Step 4 on Wiki says "Check flow field vectors for potential tracking errors and remove outliers". How do I do this in OpenCV (python)? What algorithm/function should I use? And what about steps 5 and 6? I read  somewhere (see third comment http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/optical-flow-with-kalman-filter-td6578617.html) that Kalman Filter would not give any improvement in performance if Lucas Kanade is used.

Comment: Can you rebuild opencv?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7388893/extract-transform-and-rotation-matrices-from-homography?rq=1

Comment: I'm still a beginner, but I can say one say. As far as I know, removing outliers are done by RANSAC algorithm. And there's many algorithms in OpenCV that use RANSAC method, given to it as a flag.
I don't actually think that you need to implement all these stuff by yourself, maybe there's a function in OpenCV for the whole algorithm .. maybe not. I'm still searching. If I reached something, I'd let you know.

Answer (score 1):

As for removing vectors with errors, you should filter keypoints in accordance with status returned by calcOpticalFlowPyrLK. The following code can help you with it:

```
def featureTracking(image_ref, image_cur, px_ref):
    kp2, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(image_ref, image_cur, px_ref, None, **lk_params)  # shape: [k,2] [k,1] [k,1]

    st = st.reshape(st.shape[0])
    kp1 = px_ref[st == 1]
    kp2 = kp2[st == 1]

    return kp1, kp2
```

As for steps 5 and 6, find essential matrix and estimate pose using it (openCV functions `findEssentialMat` and `recoverPose`. You can look through these examples:

- https://github.com/uoip/monoVO-python
- https://github.com/luigifreda/pyslam

And read this two posts:

- https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/visual-odometry-full/
- https://avisingh599.github.io/vision/monocular-vo/